# Need help on how to apply arcade kit commands in Python code

Tags: pi-3, python

I'm using Python on my Raspberry Pi to code some games for my high school finals project, and I want to play them with a arcade kit (Game DIY Arcade Set Kits Replacement Parts USB Encoder to PC Joystick and Buttons). I already tested the arcade kit and it works perfectly in the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I tested the arcade kit with https://html5gamepad.com/

Already went to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html and tried to code myself the buttons, but still nothing.

There is one of the games if it helps

```
import random    
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PIPE = (0,255,128)
SKY = (102,178,255)
GROUND = (192,192,192)
GRASS = (0,153,76)
BIRD = (255,255,0)
BROWN = (124,115,46)
RED = (204,0,0)


size = (800,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Block")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

arial18 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial',18, False, False)
arial30 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial',30, False, False)

gameState = 1

pipes = []

Pontuação = 0
pontuaçãoMáxima = 0

class Bird():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.yV = 0

    def flap(self):
        self.yV = -10

    def update(self):
        self.yV += 0.5
        self.y += self.yV
        if self.y >= 608:
            self.y = 608
            self.yV = 0
        if self.yV > 20:
            self.yV = 20

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BIRD,(self.x,self.y,40,40))

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.yV = 0

bird = Bird()

class Pipe():
    def __init__(self):
        self.centerY = random.randrange(130,520)
        self.x = 800
        self.size = 100

    def update(self):
        global pipes
        global bird
        global gameState
        global Pontuação
        self.x -= 4
        if self.x == 300:
            pipes.append(Pipe())
        if self.x <= -100:
            del pipes[0]
        if self.x >= 170 and self.x <= 290 and bird.y <= (self.centerY - self.size) or self.x >= 170 and self.x <= 290 and (bird.y + 40) >= (self.centerY + self.size):
            gameState = 3
        if self.x == 168 and bird.y > (self.centerY - 100) and bird.y < (self.centerY + 100):
            Pontuação += 1
        if bird.y >= 608:
            gameState = 3

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,PIPE,(self.x,0,80,(self.centerY - self.size)))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,PIPE,(self.x,(self.centerY + self.size),80,(548 - self.centerY)))

pipes.append(Pipe())

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if gameState == 1:
                    gameState = 2
                elif gameState == 3:
                    bird.reset()
                    pipes = []
                    pipes.append(Pipe())
                    gameState = 2
                    Pontuação = 0
                else:
                    bird.flap()

    screen.fill(SKY)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GROUND,(0,650,800,50))
    pygame.draw.line(screen,GRASS,(0,650),(800,650),5)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,GRASS,(0,650),(800,650),5)

    if gameState == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(300,300,220,100))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(300,300,220,100),5)
        text = arial18.render("Prima um botão para jogar",True,GRASS)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((410 - (textX / 2)),(350 - (textY / 2))))

    if gameState == 2:
        bird.update()
        bird.draw()

        for pipe in pipes:
            pipe.update()
            pipe.draw()

        if Pontuação > pontuaçãoMáxima:
            pontuaçãoMáxima = Pontuação

        text = arial30.render(str(Pontuação),True,WHITE)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((400 - (textX / 2)),(50 - (textY / 2))))

    if gameState == 3:
        for pipe in pipes:
            pipe.draw()
        bird.draw()

        pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(300,250,220,200))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(300,250,220,200),5)
        text = arial18.render(("Pontuação: " + str(Pontuação)),True,GRASS)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((410 - (textX / 2)),(300 - (textY / 2))))
        text = arial18.render(("Pontuação Máxima: " + str(pontuaçãoMáxima)),True,GRASS)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((410 - (textX / 2)),(350 - (textY / 2))))
        text = arial18.render("Prima um botão para jogar",True,GRASS)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((410 - (textX / 2)),(400 - (textY / 2))))
        text = arial30.render(str(Pontuação),True,WHITE)
        textX = text.get_rect().width
        textY = text.get_rect().height
        screen.blit(text,((410 - (textX / 2)),(50 - (textY / 2))))

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: what is the problem and what is your question?

Comment: I can't use an arcade kit (joystick and buttons) that I bought I believe the problem is in the code, however I can't anything in the Internet.